# How do I get my joystick to work with Touhou 7.5 Immaterial and Missing Power?

Tags: touhou-immaterial-and-missing-power

I downloaded Touhou 7.5 Immaterial and Missing Power the other day, and I've never been very good at playing Fighters on the keyboard.

I have an SFxT Fight stick that is for the Xbox 360, but works with PC because its for the 360 (Microsoft). I use for it SSF4 on the PC so it does 100% work fine. I just can't get it to work on Touhou 7.5. When I try to config it, it never picks up the joystick.

Would I need some sort of driver for the game/joystick itself or a version of the game that supports joystick use? I've tried to look for a version that has joystick compatibility, but I can't seem to find anything.

Comment: Are you sure that the trial version you downloaded supports joysticks?

Comment: @Kaze have you tried installing the [360 controller drivers](http://www.microsoft.com/hardware/en-us/downloads#gaming)?

Answer (score -1):

Don't think that just because a pad is from microsoft it will automatically work. If there is a configure option on the game itts worth looking at.

I had the same problem a few years back with test drive. If all else fails and you don't have spare time to wait for an answer, use a search engine to do research.

Comment: I didnt think it would automatically work... but it doesnt and thats why im asking for help.. and advice??? and no I said in configuration the joystick doesnt get picked up... so thats a no also, and I did look but I didnt find much

Comment: Spoke to the manufacturer or the game support? It could be a case of just a fualty pad in which case you could try and take it back.

Comment: The question even says it works with SFF4 on the PC, so it's not a hardware fault.